# Slickgrid excel-export service not assignable to "External Recourses" in grid options in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, slickgrid, aurelia-slickgrid

After reading the How To [Guide](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Export-to-Excel) for adding the excel-export option in aurelia-slickgrid after versions 3.0.0, I have this error in `registerExternalResources: []`:
[image]

Also I imported and initialized it as it follows:

```
import { ExcelExportService } from "@slickgrid-universal/excel-export";
this.excelExportService = new ExcelExportService();
```

The version of aurelia-slickgrid that I am using is

> 3.12.1

And I have the grid options enabling the excel export.

Any suggestions why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to make sure that you did install the Excel Export package since that one is optional. Also you need to make sure you're using the correct  version of Slickgrid-Universal package(s), I create this [table - wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Versions-Compatibility-Table) to show which versions are compatible with each other. If you're on Aurelia-Slickgrid 3.x then your Slickgrid-Universal package(s) versions needs to be version 0.19.2, if you use a different version it will throw a bunch of interface errors like you currently have... in other words, each Aurelia-Slickgrid version are very specific to only 1 version of Slickgrid-Universal which is why I created that [table - wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Versions-Compatibility-Table)

Also worth to know that each breaking change version have their migration guide to follow, it is also very important that you follow them in order when upgrading. For example [Migration Guide to 3.x](https://github.com/ghiscoding/aurelia-slickgrid/wiki/Migration-to-3.x) is the one you should follow in your case

Comment: Thanks for your answer again! In my case I did install separately the Excel Export package, but I had the latest version. Indeed, this was causing the interface error, so I had to downgrade to the 0.19.2 as you mentioned and it worked like a charm!